# disable javascript for specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to disable javascript for specific element only?

Suppose, div with id foo has some javascript code may be it's inline, internal, or external javascript code.

Now, unbind all javascript code for that element (may be also to including children).

Comment: Not sure you can do it. For inline - yes, if it did not run yet. For all others - they are parsed at the moment when page is loading and after that they do not have any specific location, as I think.

Comment: In the top of the head script runs first and will make sure to disable javascript for that, no?

Comment: Nope, as I think. The DOM element will be accessible after its parsing by browser. Don't think there is a way to get into the processing to prevent js blocks.

Comment: remember that if an element is replaced, even with itself, any events bound to it will be lost. This won't help with delegated events but may be of use in your situation. Also could parse attributes for various inline handlers and remove them

Comment: @charlietfl—that depends on how the "events were bound" and how the element is replaced.

Comment: @RobG I realize that and am speaking in generalities also, just passing on a concept is all. Can run into numerous timing issues also as to when events do get bound

Comment: While it is possible to remove listeners on a particular element by jumping through a number of hoops to remove listeners assigned using inline code, property assignment and *addEventListener*, those added using *attachEvent* might be trickier. Also, how do you prevent event delegation?

Comment: Not only that, it's even more difficult if you're using a library like *jQuery* where a listener is actually bound to an ancestor, but applied to children that meet a defined criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### CSS `pointer-events` property

Turn off the CSS pointer-events property.

```
#foo { pointer-events: none; }
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events.

Of course this will **not** turn off certain types of event handlers such as, say, the `onchange` handler on an input element. On the other hand, it has the advantage that you can turn `pointer-events` back on for specific descendant elements if you want.

No support in IE < 11.

#### Adding a new event handler

Alternatively, you could also try the following:

```
elt.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

This will not stop any event handlers already attached directly to the element from running, but it will stop the event from bubbling, which will deal with delegation-type situations. It will suppress any future event handlers added to the element from running. It will also suppress the default behavior of the event (such as a click on a link).

You will have to do this for each event type individually. There is no way to define event handlers that apply to multiple or all events (which you probably wouldn't want to do anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no jQuery (perhaps it would work with it too?), isn't the solution as simple as:
`element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;` ?

I.e set the text representation of everything the node contains to be the current text representation of everything the node contains. Text assignments like this nuke any/all handlers bound with `element.addEventListener`. You could also use `element.removeAttribute('inlineEventName')` to nuke anything in the html itself.

You could just set the .innerHTML or .outerHTML to be a copy of whatever it already is and then, then loop through an array of handler names and repeatedly call .removeAttribute. 
Iterating through the child nodes of any target, and again (this time for each item) loop through an array of names of hander names you'd like to kill. Perhaps there's a way to iterate through the list of handler names, I dont know - I'd just create an array of all of the ones find and step through that array, nuking as required. You'd kill all of the JS-attached handlers in the initial replacement, then would need to remove the inline handlers for the node and any/all children.

Here's a quick example that disables everything in the body and its children. You'll notice that the first time around, the 'kill' notice fires twice - once from the inline handler and once from the js-added handler. The second time around, the notice only fires once. This time from the inline handler.
Try removing it or using `.removeAttribute` as I suggested earlier to nuke that handler too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    byId('mFileInput').addEventListener('change', onFileChosen, false);
    byId('mBtn').addEventListener('click', killPageJs, false);
}
function killPageJs(evt)
{
    alert('killed');
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
}

// fileVar is an object as returned by <input type='file'>
// imgElem is an <img> element - can be on/off screen (doesn't need to be added to the DOM)
function loadImgFromFile(fileVar, imgElem)
{
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = onFileLoaded;
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(fileVar);
    function onFileLoaded(fileLoadedEvent)
    {
        var result,data;
        data = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        result = "data:";
        result += fileVar.type;
        result += ";base64,";
        result += btoa(data);
        imgElem.src = result;
        imgElem.origType = fileVar.type;    // unnecessary for loading the image, used by a current project.
    }
}

function onFileChosen(evt)
{
    if (this.files.length != 0)
    {
        var tgtImg = byId('tgt');
        var curFile = this.files[0];
        loadImgFromFile(curFile, tgtImg);
    }
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id='mBtn' onclick='killPageJs();'>Kill</button><hr>
    <input id='mFileInput' type='file'/><br>
    <img id='tgt' />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, there's not a way to access/loop through handlers. You can remove `onClick` handles etc. by removing the attribute, but you cannot find or remove any handles set with `addEventListener` etc.

Comment: Thought as much. The `addEventListner` ones are trivial, since they disappear with the initial text replacement.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can you can use this

```
document.querySelector("element id or class here").style.pointerEvents = "none";
```

Comment: @LajosArpad how does this not provide an answer. This looks like it directly addresses the OP's original inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jquery's `.off()` function to remove the event handler.

Calling `.off()` with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements.

https://api.jquery.com/off/